# Maclaurin Polynomial and Remainder Theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, taylor-expansion

I need help with this question, it would be greatly appreciated if I could get any help.

f(x)=1/(1−x) 
a) Enter the degree- nterm in the Maclaurin polynomial.

For this question, I calculated that the nth term is x^n.

b)Enter the remainder term Rn(z) which will also be a function of x and n.

I calculated that for this function f(n)=n!
I thought the remainder theorem for this particular function was

(n+1)!/(n+1)!(x)^(n+1)
Hence, x^(n+1)

But I got it completely wrong,

I just want to know where I got this wrong
Thank you

Comment: You calculated just the next term in the Maclaurin polynomial, not the remainder, (BTW, $f(n) \ne n!$. $f(x) = 1/(1-x)$, so $f(n) = 1/(1-n)$. Be careful with your notation.) As for the remainder, there are a variety of expressions (Lagrange form, Cauchy, Integral form, and also just subtracting the polynomial from $f(x)$). We don't know which one is being requested here. (Since you introduce a new variable $z$, maybe the Lagrange or Cauchy forms?, Or is the $z$ a typo?)